# Using Enum and | as dictionary key

Tags: c#, dictionary, enums

I'm trying to use a dictionary with an enum type as its key and a string as its value.

Here is my enum:

```
public enum MilitaryBranch{
    AirForce,
    Army,
    Navy,
    Marines,
    Coastguard
}
```

And here is my Dictionary

```
Dictionary<MilitaryBranch, string> BranchToRankMapping = new Dictionary<MilitaryBranch, string>()
{
    {    MilitaryBranch.AirForce|MilitaryBranch.Army|MilitaryBranch.Marines, "General" },
    {    MilitaryBranch.Navy, "Admiral" },
    {    MilitaryBranch.Coastguard, "Commandant" },
}
```

In the dictionary, I was trying to use the | operator to OR AirForce, Army, And Marines together so that if any of those enums were provided as a Key to the dictionary, it would return "General".

Here is my use of the dictionary and the enum:

```
public void Test(){
    string af = BranchToRankMapping[MilitaryBranch.AirForce];
    string army = BranchToRankMapping[MilitaryBranch.Army];
    string marines = BranchToRankMapping[MilitaryBranch.Marines];
    string navy = BranchToRankMapping[MilitaryBranch.Navy];
    string cg= BranchToRankMapping[MilitaryBranch.Coastguard];
}
```

When trying to get the dictionary value for MilitaryBranch.AirForce, .Army, and .Marines I am getting a Key not found exception.

Is what I am trying to do not possible? Do I have to put in a dictionary item for each enum value? Thanks

Comment: wishful thinking. You will have to create entries for each type, no simple way to may dictionary lookup do an 'or' operation

Comment: You could roll your own and deeply couple it to your use-case.

Comment: if you want to see whats happening do this `int val = (int)(MilitaryBranch.AirForce|MilitaryBranch.Army|MilitaryBranch.Marines)` to see what key actually gets used

Comment: Personally, I'd just consider creating a [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) to do the mapping (vs. a Dictionary).

Comment: Or, a switch statement, where you could stack things up over "General"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless otherwise specified, an enum maps to an integral value. Dictionary lookups will be based on the integral value of the enumerated value.

Since you didn't override the values assigned to your enum, they number from zero. This means AirForce == 0, Army == 1, and so on.

When you combine `AirForce | Army | Marines`, you're really doing `0 | 1 | 3`, which is 3.

The way you've set up your dictionary, you've added entries for the integral values of 3 (with the bitwise operand), 2 (for Navy) and 4 (for Marines).

I'm afraid the simplest approach for what you want is to add an explicit entry for each branch of the military.

Comment: I significantly simplified the example for the purposes of asking the question so I was hoping this would work haha. I guess I better get coding. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Depending on your use case, if you have a large number of options with lots of overlap, it might be best to ditch the dictionary and use a simple method with a `switch` statement. You can combine cases that way, and return the value you desire from each case. If you need to keep the values around, though, and it's not a simple static value for each key, that may not work.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, an entry for each one.

```
Dictionary<MilitaryBranch, string> BranchToRankMapping = new Dictionary<MilitaryBranch, string>()
{
    {    MilitaryBranch.AirForce, "General" },
    {    MilitaryBranch.Army, "General" },
    {    MilitaryBranch.Marines, "General" },
    {    MilitaryBranch.Navy, "Admiral" },
    {    MilitaryBranch.Coastguard, "Commandant" },
}
```

Answer (score 2):

By `MilitaryBranch.AirForce|MilitaryBranch.Army|MilitaryBranch.Marines` you are doing a `bitwise OR` which results in 3 which is equivalent of `MilitaryBranch.Marines` in your case.

Hence you will get a value for `BranchToRankMapping[MilitaryBranch.Marines]` and not for `BranchToRankMapping[MilitaryBranch.AirForce]` or `BranchToRankMapping[MilitaryBranch.Army]`.

So yes we need to have an entry for each value in your enum.